# Create Pandas Dataframe from different numpy arrays; one column should contain a row from my array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

In my code, I have data stored in numpy arrays. I want to save my data to a csv file using Pandas. Additionally, I want my data to have a special format in the csv file.

My data:

```py
data1 = np.array([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])  
data2 = np.array([10,11,12])   
data3 = np.array([13,14,15])
```

What I want: a csv file that has three colums labeled `'data1'`, `'data2'` and `'data3'`.
`'data1'` should have 3 rows with row 1 containing the values 1,2,3 (or 1 2 3), row 2 should contain 4,5,6 (or 4 5 6) and so on.
The column labeled as `'data2'` should contain 10 in row 1, 11 in row 12 and 13 in row 3.
Similar for `'data 3'`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the constraints described in the question, this is how I would approach this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])  # list of lists in declaration
data2 = np.array([10,11,12])   
data3 = np.array([13,14,15])

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(data1, data2, data3), columns=['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], dtype='str')
df['data1'] = df['data1'].str.replace('[', '').str.replace(']', '')
df.to_csv('./out.csv', index=False)  # saving to file in cwd with name 'out.csv'
```

Resulting in `out.csv` containing:

```
data1,data2,data3
1 2 3,10,13
4 5 6,11,14
7 8 9,12,15
```

---

**EDIT**:

To answer the comment below regarding converting back from csv of the above format to the original arrays:

```py
# let pandas infer the data types (data1: str, data2: int, data3: int. By default)
df = pd.read_csv('./out.csv')

# convert each entry in data1 to a numpy array using fromstring method
df['data1'] = df['data1'].apply(lambda x : np.fromstring(x, sep=' '))

# nuance to get series of arrays back to numpy.ndarray
data1 = np.array(df['data1'].to_list())

# simply use to_numpy method for integer columns
data2 = df['data2'].to_numpy()
data3 = df['data3'].to_numpy()
```

Comment: Is there also a simple way to read the values from the csv file and restore the original arrays?